# Why all ferro-electric materials are also pyro-electrics?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, crystals, piezoelectric

Ferro-electricity is the property of some dielectric materials to keep a net residual polarization even after the electric field is removed. They tipically present a hysteresis cycle doing this.

- It is said that [all ferro-electrics are also pyro-electrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity), but why is this?

I know that Pyro-electricity is due to an asymmetry of position of negative and positive ions in the crystal structure, such that when thermally dilatated a net polarization is created along some direction. Pervoskite is one such crystal structure that permits this:

[image: \text{Pervoskite structure under pyro-electric effect}]

Note: a similar effect is found in Piezo-electrics where it's instead a mechanical stress to force a polarization in certain directions. While there could exist some piezo-electric material *not* pyro-electric, is not true the opposite. I believe the reason for this is that more modes of deformation are available to mechanical deformation rather than those to thermal deformation, moreover all modes of deformation are coverable by a certain mechanical deformation.

But i don't understand the necessary connection between Ferro-electricity and Pyro-electricity, where respectively electric field and thermal deformation are involved, in particular **why does not exist any ferro-electric material which is *not* pyro-electric?**

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: They are linked through the reduced symmetry of the crystals (non-cubic) leading to those effects. Or, ferro- and pyro-electricity are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Actually not all pyroelectrics are also ferroelectrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think crystal structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyroelectricity) explains this. Say if the pervoskite (which is pyro with natural polarisation P) red atom jumps from upper half to lower half of gold enclosure and polarisation reverses to downward direction when applying an electrical field, then it is ferroelectric too, otherwise only pyroelectric. So perhaps it is an electric potential energy barrier issue that determines ferroelectricity of a polar crystal which is always pyro.

Note, this assumes stable reversal. High intensity and / or short-lived reversals can happen and if observed can settle your disquiet.

Comment: Actually my understanding was that all unit cell deform, when stress or thermal or electric field applies. Also from a macroscopic level is impossible to say if polarization happened because of 'reversal' or not, we can just observe if polarization is kept after electric field is removed. But thinking about it, i realized that the reason might be that inclined dipoles align, leaving polarization even after electric field is removed. And this can only happen if dipoles are already present in matter, as piezoelectricity does not necessarly need that, ferroelectric must also be pyroelectric

Comment: but i still don't understand why some pyroelectrics (then with pre-existing polarization) are not ferroelectric also

Comment: Perhaps my answer was not explicit enough for illustration. Let's for the explanation assume for heuristic purposes that the single crystal cell is electro-statically neutral but as in the pervoskite-like structure you showed, that the red atom is +vely charged, balanced by the rest of the atoms in the single cell. Because of the asymmetry in its position the dipole manifests as shown. Were that atom in the reflection opposite position, the dipole would have reversed, no? If yes, then if it could be moved (energy barrier allowing) there by an external field, then it would be ferroelectric.

Comment: And to account for macroscopic manifestation one can assume equidistant red atoms more stable than a mix of closer / further random arrangement in selection of which asymmetric offset to stabilise on after the electric field is removed. Hence a macro polarisation which should also be observerbale across an aggregate multicrystal body each one randomly aligned.

Comment: Ok now i understand your point, and seems to be quite reasonable. So if i understood well, net residual polazation arises in a medium as a consequence of how many 'conclusive' reversals occur, since reversals remain after E is removed and their dipole summation is aligned with E, material remains polarized. This though does not happen for all pyroelectrics, since some of them do not have a suitable energy barrier configuration. But, in that case, why woudn't just be a matter of using a larger electric field intensity?

Comment: And by what specifically is set up this energy barrier? Would be this also the cause of the initial asymmetry of the cell?

Comment: Now we're getting closer. Take another look at the pervoskite-like structure. Compare it to say a structural model of the benzene ring (six carbon hexagon, with alternating single / dual bonds). It is known that there are actually two structural representations, yes? And they are isomers (or isomeric views) of the same thing. And how they actually live is a fusion of the two. Well the structure you've drawn is one cell isomer of the crystal since the 'upside-down' one is equally valid. No 'reversal' required, except in your cortex. Which one dominates is an accident of condensation.

Comment: Finally, the energy barrier heuristic is generic to all crystal structures, not only polar ( ferro / pyro / piezo). Imangine if that red atom was relatively so big that to occupy the mirrored state requires changes in interatomic separation of the gold and blue atoms. That makes reversal not so prevalent compared to say small reds that do not perturb the structure of the but jump back and forth freely and thereby show a bright spectral line for that ferro transition. The only thing that keeps them polarised is the stable inter-cell separation I mentioned before. Ergo your ferro-electrics.

Comment: Also see last para of my initial answer on high intensity fields. The wikipedia reference cites 32 crystal structure classes. Not very long ago when I was a student all text books cited 16. The difference being that experimentation was able to record less stable structures through high intensity conditions in non-isobaric, non-adiabatic set-ups to consistently identify new crystal structures not normally found in ambient conditions.

Comment: But still what about a sufficiently intense field for the case of the big red atom? Wouldn't it create polarization till saturation, as for a smaller red atoms situation?

Comment: In your graphic illustration of pyroelectric pervoskite, increased temperature increased outer lattice spacing and allowed the red atom to occupy more symmetric position at center for low to zero polarization. The same would be needed for 'big' reds, to reverse polarisation. But imagine if it was big and hot enough to cross center line, then the crystal structure can change to something else, and no longer pervoskite as such and may not have a stable reversal to settle into residually. You can end up with a recrystallized (annealed) substrate, not necessarily aligned like in a single crystal.

Comment: I think I did not motivate previous comment adequately (characters limit). The 'mechanics' of the piezo, ferro and pyro palarisation differ, but spatial anisotropic distribution of charge is the manifestation. It is possible heating can allow electric field reversal of big reds, but it is not guaranteed on thermal recrystalization. From my undergraduate project work I remember measuring the Helmoltz free energy of recrystallization of Cu at approx. 4.8KJ/Mole. You'd have to make sure the annealing under strong electric field has much lower relative energy than your ferro-transition barrier.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the clarification, i think your last phrase explains the thing, if i understood correctly you are saying that an electric field sufficiently big to move the big red atom might be also sufficiently big to displace the other atoms in the cell such to cause a crystal structure change, for which any polarization results impractical